# Google Chrome Inspector on Remote Devices not working

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, devtools, inspector

I'm working on an **Android App** that uses **WebView** and wanted to use the inspector in order to check some things. 
The problem is the elements are not visible or other tabs seem not be working, they are blank.

Does somebody else experience this issue? or is there a workaround rather than downgrading the chrome version on your system?

Since **Google Chrome** updated to version **80** the panel for **Remote Devices** has been deprecated and it's required to go on: `chrome://inspect/devices#devices` 
(Note: Inspector on Remote Devices was **working fine** on **Chrome 78-79**)

[image]

Comment: This is not reproducable. Tried with Version 80.0.3987.162 (PC) and 80.0.3987.149 (Android). Could you please provide the source of information, claiming it would be deprecated? Unless it is obsoleted, this still should work.

Comment: The information is being provided by the inspector. If you go `Inspect` -> `More tools` -> `Remote Devices` you will see the message: ***This panel has been deprecated in favor of the  `chrome://inspect#devices` interface, which has equivalent functionality***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Chrome 80 to work on the emulator is required to have an API > 26
This is required because the WebView version will be updated based on the emulator API and ***Chrome 80 removed support for HTML imports and (very) old versions of DevTools do not have the polyfill built in to prevent crashing.*** ([link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1067220) for open chromium bug)
API 26 has 58.0.3029 WebView version - works for older versions of Chrome < 80 
API 28 has 69.0.3497.100 WebView version - works on Chrome 80

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);`?
I don't experience an error if I use this code.

> Also you can read more at [developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews)

Comment: Yes, I added that at the begging, otherwise, you won't be able to inspect

Comment: You can try putting your issue to [https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be OK to use an older Chrome/Chromiun version instead ? ... do you know where to grab/build one guys ? - thnx!

Comment: Hi, you can get older versions of Chrome from here: https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

Comment: Yes, Staying on Chrome 79 solves the problem (at least for me). You just have to be careful to not re-activate chrome automatic upadte.